# fourier coefficient of an impulse train

Tags: complex-analysis

HI: I'm going through the signals and systems Schaum's book and I don't understand something that I hope someone could clear up for me. I will repeat the question and then  explain the part where I'm confused.

Consider the impulse train defined by

$\delta_{t_{0}}(t) = \sum_{k= -\infty}^{\infty} \delta(t - kT_{0})$.

They show a picture which is a series of spikes each separated by the distance $T_{0}$.
But I can't show it here, atleast easily.

The question is:

a) Determine the complex exponential Fourier series of $\delta_{T_{0}}(t)$.

b) Determine the trigonometric Fourier series of $\delta_{T_{0}}(t)$.

Then they go through the solution and the part I don't get is the following:

They have: $c_{k} = \frac{1}{T_{0}} \int_{-\frac{T_{0}}{2}}^\frac{T_{0}}{2} \delta(t) \exp^{-jkw_{0} t} dt = \frac{1}{T_{0}}$.

I don't understand how they obtain $\frac{1}{T_{0}}$. Thank you very much for any help with this. Oh, I assume that the leaving out of the $T_{0}$ as the subscript of $\delta(t)$
in the integral was just a typo. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Recall the *sifting property* of the dirac delta function. In general, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\tau)\delta(\tau-(t-T))d\tau = f(t-T)$. This can be useful in simplifying integral expressions

$$c_{k} = \frac{1}{T_{0}} \int_{-\frac{T_{0}}{2}}^\frac{T_{0}}{2} \delta(t) \exp^{-jkw_{0} t} dt = \frac{1}{T_{0}} \exp^{0} = \frac{1}{T_{0}}$$

EDIT: Removed the term $\delta(0)$ from the expression $\frac{1}{T_{0}} \exp^{0}$.

Comment: $\delta$ is not a function but a distribution (evaluate a test function in $0$).  "$\delta(0)=1$" makes no sense.  The integral is just a notational convention: the integrand is not a function.  Instead of $\int \delta(t)f(t)dt$ the Stieltjes integral $\int f(t) dH(t)$ where $H$ is the Heaviside step function or integration with respect to a point measure are other ways to look at this.

Comment: Formally, I agree, $\delta(t)$ is defined as a distribution (measure), but one of its useful properties is that it can be manipulated like a function. I believe the sifting property is one of these *useful properties* and one way to obtain the desired result.

Comment: Hi: Thank you both. I'll look up the sifting property but accept it for now but I still don't see how you go from the integral to $\frac{1}(T_{0}} \exp^{0} $. I'm sorry for my dense-ness. thanks.

Comment: I think I understand now. The sifting property means that the value only gets "caught" at the value at which the dirac delta is 1 which is 0 in this case. I pretty much get it now so I will close out the question by checking the answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: From what WimC stated, it's best not to think of $\delta(0)=1$ (this only makes sense in the discrete time case, i.e. the Kronecker delta function). The dirac delta is a limit of normal distributions, in the limit having zero measure. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function . It has infinite amplitude, but zero width, with an 'area' of one. If this is too much to take in for now, just remember the sifting property and know how it can be useful in integral problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand properties of an impulse. Firstly, It  is defined that an impulse has an area of 1. Secondly, if you multiply f(t) with an impulse ,δ(t−kT0), it gives you the an impulse at T0 whose area is 1*f(T0). Therefore integral of δ(t)exp−jkw0t is equal to exp (0)=1.Hope you got what I mean.

Comment: Try learning [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for writing math here.